# Building qtconnectivity bluez missing

Tags: c++, qt, makefile, bluetooth

I am trying to build qtconnectivity for my host system (Ubuntu 18.04 VM) from source, revision 5.12.3.
When I try to run qmake on the project file I get this error:

```
Project ERROR: Could not find feature bluez.
```

I got every damn bluez package installed, but the bluetoothd daemon is not running, which I suppose is the problem. Here the list of bluetooth related packages I have installed:

```
udo apt list --installed | grep 'bluez\|bluetooth'

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

bluetooth/bionic-updates,bionic-updates,bionic-security,bionic-security,now 5.48-0ubuntu3.4 all [installed]
bluez/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 5.48-0ubuntu3.4 amd64 [installed,automatic]
bluez-cups/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 5.48-0ubuntu3.4 amd64 [installed,automatic]
bluez-obexd/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 5.48-0ubuntu3.4 amd64 [installed,automatic]
bluez-tools/bionic,now 0.2.0~20140808-5build1 amd64 [installed]
gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0/bionic-updates,now 3.28.0-2ubuntu0.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libbluetooth-dev/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 5.48-0ubuntu3.4 amd64 [installed]
libbluetooth3/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 5.48-0ubuntu3.4 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libbluetooth3-dbg/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 5.48-0ubuntu3.4 amd64 [installed,auto-removable]
libgnome-bluetooth13/bionic-updates,now 3.28.0-2ubuntu0.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libqt5bluetooth5/bionic,now 5.9.5-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,auto-removable]
libqt5bluetooth5-bin/bionic,now 5.9.5-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,auto-removable]
```

Anyone know how to get this error resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Often, you need to install `-dev` package to be able to use a library in compilation.

Here is the test qtconnectivity uses: https://github.com/qt/qtconnectivity/blob/dev/config.tests/bluez/main.cpp. You need a package that contains `bluetooth/bluetooth.h`.

The [search by file name in package contents](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=bluetooth%2Fbluetooth.h&mode=&suite=eoan&arch=any) reveals `libbluetooth-dev`.

Comment: Even after installing libbluetooth-dev the error remains.